# Second order differential equation falling box

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

A box is dropped from a helicopter that weighs m kg, the air resistance force is proportional to to its speed, with β being the proportionality constant, and gravity is g. y(0) = 0 and y'(0)=o initially.

How do you find the vertical position and velocity of the box in terms of these constants?

I found the second order differential equation to be:

my''+βy'=mg

but i'm not really sure what to do from here

Comment: I don't think the fact that the helicopter weighs $m$ kg gives any information about the position and velocity of the box. (Yes, I know what you _meant;_ I'm just pointing out what you _wrote_.)

Comment: Yes you're right, I just didn't want any confusion about whether I had left out the given values or something, I probably should have worded this better.

Comment: Presumably it is supposed to be the _box_ that has a mass of $m$ kg, right? Otherwise you would have to introduce a new symbol to represent the mass of the box.

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean now, yes you are right that was a mistake on my part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$y'' + {\beta\over m} y' = mg$$
Apply an integrating factor
$$y''e^{\beta t/m} + {\beta\over m}e^{\beta t/m} y' = mge^{\beta t/m}$$
so 
$$ (y'e^{\beta t/m})' = mge^{\beta t/m}$$
Can you do the rest?

Answer (score 0):

$$my''+\beta y'=mg$$
integrate both sides
$$my'+\beta y=mgt+C$$
use $y'(0)=0, y(0)=0$
$$0+\beta *0=mg(0)+C$$
$$C=0$$
$$my'+\beta y=mgt$$
$$y'+\frac{\beta}{m} y=gt$$

now you have first-order D.E.
solve it and use the condition to get $\beta$